# Creation of two select box under a form

Tags: html

I am trying to create two drop-down select box in my page..But something happening wrong ..when I run the code, the button bellow and the footer section get vanished.I tried by making `height` larger but nothing ...again when i remove the select box's code the page load properly with the register button and footer section...For more clearance  an image is given bellow.The whole code is under a form..and the form is under a div name **maincontent**..I have given the css of the **maincontent**

**here is my code**

```html
        `.maincontent {
            margin-top: 200px;
            background: #E0E0E0;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #013A57;
            padding: 3px 2px;
            margin-top: 0px;
            border-radius: 5px;
            height: 750pxmain;
            width: 900px; 
            margin-left: 15px; 
            height: 750px;
         }
        .maincontent table{

              height: 20%;
          overflow-y: scroll;
          width: 55%;
          margin-top: 30px;
          margin-left: 30px
        }
        .maincontent tr{
          background: #E0E0E0;
          border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
          margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .maincontent td{
          font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 10px;
          text-align: left;
          width: 33.3333%;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
        .maincontent h3{
            padding: 10px;
            border-bottom: 2px solid #013A57;
            margin: 10px;
            font-size: 23px;
            color: #013A57;
        }`


<div class="maincontent" style="">
 <h3>Register Here</h3>
 <div class="row justify-content-center" style="float: left;margin-left: 
         2px;margin-top: 50px">
 <div class="col" style="width: 200px">

 <?php if(!empty($msg)) { ?>
  div id="dialog" title="" style="background: #013A57; color: white;">
       <?php echo $msg;?>
  </div>
 <?php }?>

       <form method="post" action="register.php" enctype="multipart/form- data" 
         style="width: 860px;margin: 0px;height: 580px;">

             <input class="form-control" type="" name="name" placeholder="Name..." 
         style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

             <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" 
         placeholder="Email..." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

             <input class="form-control" type="password" name="password" 
         placeholder="Password" style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>

          <input class="form-control" type="password" name="cPassword" 
         placeholder="confirm Password..." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" 
         ><br>

          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="contactNO" placeholder="Your 
         contact No.." style="width: 400px; margin-left: 200px" ><br>


      <div class="radio">

       <h6>Select a Category</h6>

       <input type="radio" name="category" value="customer">Customer<br>

       <input type="radio" name="category" value="DispensaryOwner">Dispensary 
         Owner<br>

       <input type="radio" name="category" value="dealer">Dealer<br>

      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="address radio" >

       <h6 style="margin-left: 20px">Address</h6>
            
       <select name="district" id="district">
        <option value="">Select District</option>
        <?php echo load_district(); ?>
       </select>
       <br>
       <select name="place" id="place">
        <option value="">Select place</option>
      </select>

         </div>

         <br>

          <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"
      style=" margin-left: 200px"><br><br>

          </form>
         </div>
  
        </div>
 
    </div>
```

**Image Before**

[image]

**Image After**

[image]

Comment: I edit your code as snippet, can you add your css in this snippet so people can reproduce what you get?